# Sieve of Erastosthenes highest prime factor in erlang

Tags: erlang, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have edited the program so that it works(with small numbers) however I do not understand how to implement an accumulator as suggested. The reason why is because P changes throughout the process, therefore I do not know in with which granularity I should break up the mother list. The Sieve of Erastosthenes is only efficient for generating smaller primes, so maybe I should have picked a different algorithm to use. Can anybody recommend a decent algorithm for calculating the highest prime factor of 600851475143? Please do not give me code I would prefer a Wikipedia article of something of that nature.

```
    -module(sieve).
    -export([find/2,mark/2,primes/1]).

    primes(N) -> [2|lists:reverse(primes(lists:seq(2,N),2,[]))].

    primes(_,bound_reached,[_|T]) -> T;
    primes(L,P,Primes) -> NewList = mark(L,P),
        NewP = find(NewList,P),
        primes(NewList,NewP,[NewP|Primes]).

    find([],_) -> bound_reached;
    find([H|_],P) when H > P -> H;
    find([_|T],P) -> find(T,P). 


    mark(L,P) -> lists:reverse(mark(L,P,2,[])).

    mark([],_,_,NewList) -> NewList;
    mark([_|T],P,Counter,NewList) when Counter rem P =:= 0 -> mark(T,P,Counter+1,[P|NewList]);
    mark([H|T],P,Counter,NewList) -> mark(T,P,Counter+1,[H|NewList]).
```

I found writing this very difficult and I know there are a few things about it that are not very elegant, such as the way I have 2 hardcoded as a prime number. So I would appreciate any C&C and also advice about how to attack these kinds of problems. I look at other implementations and I have absoulutely no idea how the authors think in this way but its something I would like to master.

I have worked out that I can forget the list up until the most recent prime number found, however I have no idea how I am supposed to produce an end bound (subtle humour). I think there is probably something I can use like lists:seq(P,something) and the Counter would be able to handle that as I use modulo rather than resetting it to 0 each time. Ive only done AS level maths so I have no idea what this is.

I cant even do that can I? because I will have to remove multiples of 2 from the entirety of the list. Im thinking that this algorithm will not work unless I cache data to the harddrive, so I'm back to looking for a better algorithm.

I'm now considering writing an algorithm that just uses a counter and keeps a list of primes which are numbers that do not divide evenly with the previously generated prime numbers is this a good way to do it?

This is my new algorithm that I wrote I think it should work but I get the following error "sieve2.erl:7: call to local/imported function is_prime/2 is illegal in guard" I think this is just an aspect of erlang that I do not understand. However I've no idea how I could find the material to read about it. [Im purposely not using higher order functions etc as I have only read upto the bit on recursion in learnyousomeerlang.org]

```
    -module(sieve2).
    -export([primes/1]).

    primes(N) -> primes(2,N,[2]).

    primes(Counter,Max,Primes) when Counter =:= Max -> Primes;
    primes(Counter,Max,Primes) when is_prime(Counter,Primes) -> primes(Counter+1,Max,[Counter|Primes]);
    primes(Counter,Max,Primes) -> primes(Counter+1,Max,Primes).

    is_prime(X, []) -> true;
    is_prime(X,[H|T]) when X rem H =:= 0 -> false;
    is_prime(X,[H|T]) -> prime(X,T).
```

The 2nd algorithm does not crash but runs too slowly, I'm thinking that I should reimplement the 1st but this time forget the numbers up until the most recently discovered prime, does anybody know what I could use as an end bound? After looking at other solutions it seems people sometimes just set an arbitrary limit i.e 2 million (this is something I do not really want to do. Others used "lazy" implementations which is what I think I am doing.

Comment: Here's someone trying to solve the exact same problem you are, but not in Erlang.  The comments and answers may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439814/prime-factor-of-300-000-000-000

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
lists:seq(2,N div 2)
```

allocates a list, and as the [efficiency guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) says, a list requires at least two words of memory per element.  (A word is 4 or 8 bytes, depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit Erlang virtual machine.)  So if `N` is 600851475143, this would require 48 terabytes of memory if I count correctly.  (Unlike Haskell, Erlang doesn't do lazy evaluation.)

So you'd need to implement this using an accumulator, similar to what you did with `Counter` in the `mark` function.  For the stop condition of the recursive function, you wouldn't check for the list being empty, but for the accumulator reaching the max value.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you don't need to test all numbers up to N/2. It is enough to test up to sqrt(N).

[Here I wrote a version that takes 20 seconds to find the answer on my machine.](https://github.com/RumataEstor/project_euler/blob/master/problem003.erl) It uses kind of lazy list of primes and folding through them. It was fun because I solved some project-euler problems using Haskell quite a long ago and to use the same approach on Erlang was a bit of strange.

Comment: It would be much faster if you would divide by the factors you find.

Comment: Divide what? I have a list of primes, I take each of them up to sqrt(N) and check if a prime is a factor of N.

Comment: N, so the remaining number becomes much smaller.

Comment: Ah, I see. I find (Prime ^ K) * N1 = N and then can look for factors of N1 instead of N. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your update3:

```
primes(Counter,Max,Primes) when Counter =:= Max -> Primes;
primes(Counter,Max,Primes) when is_prime(Counter,Primes) -> primes(Counter+1,Max,[Counter|Primes]);
primes(Counter,Max,Primes) -> primes(Counter+1,Max,Primes).
```

You cannot use your own defined functions as guard clauses as in Haskell. You have to rewrite it to use it in a case statement:

```
primes(Counter,Max,Primes) when Counter =:= Max ->
    Primes;
primes(Counter,Max,Primes) ->
    case is_prime(Counter,Primes) of
        true ->
            primes(Counter+1,Max,[Counter|Primes]);
        _ ->
            primes(Counter+1,Max,Primes)
    end.
```